# objective c profiler for gnustep

Tags: objective-c, performance, gnustep

Is there a profiler for Objective-C run on the linux.
I'm using the GNUstep environment.
I searched on the website of GNUstep, there's nothing about profiler.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a special profiler for Objective-C applications. Any profiler for Linux (such as gprof) should work just fine.